# On counting certain binary matrices?

Tags: combinatorics, matrices

Consider a square binary matrix $A=[a_{ij}]_n$ with $a_{ii}=0,\forall i=1,2,\cdots,n$ and satisfying the following two condition:

$a_{ij}=1\Rightarrow a_{jk}=0, \forall k=1,2,3,\cdots,n$

$a_{ij}=1\Rightarrow a_{ki}=0,\forall k=1,2,3,\cdots,n$

How many such matrices exist for a general $n\in\mathbb{N}$? In other words, if $a_n$ is the number of all such matrices for a specific $n$, what is $a_n$?

I got $a_1=1, a_2=3,a_3=13.$

***PS: The idea is the following: If a row/column, say the ith contains at least one $1$, the ith column/row contains only $0$s.***

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133608/discussion-on-question-by-firdous-ahmad-mala-on-counting-certain-binary-matrices).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [OEIS A001831](https://oeis.org/A001831), the number of simultaneously transitive and antitransitive relations on $n$ elements. A formula is provided there:
$$a_n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk(2^k-1)^{n-k}$$